# How to clear the text when clicked on any other controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net

the below js script works fine but there is small problem and the problem is that:

i have a textbox with multiline and when the user clicks on it and it does clear the textbox but the problem is; when the user click on Save button (asp.net control button) to save the textbox value and i want that to ignore on code behind and also client side.

one thing i can do is to compare the value and clear if it is matached but what if; if i have many controls and dont want to spread the string every where in the code...

looking for a optimized solution.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNew" 
onclick="if (this.value == 'Enter here...') this.value = ''" TextMode="MultiLine"
Rows="7" Width="100%">Enter here...</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to hardcode your `Enter here...`, use [`defaultValue`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp) instead.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNew" 
onclick="if (this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value = ''" TextMode="MultiLine"
Rows="7" Width="100%">Enter here...</asp:TextBox>
```

For the codebehind part of your question:

I would recommend to use a `RequiredFieldValidator` (since "Enter here" suggests that it's mandatory). Then you can use the [`InititalValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue.aspx) property for your default text, hence the user must enter something to submit the page.

Comment: @AbuHamzah: Actually you don't need to define it all. It's implicitely defined by the text assigned to the TextBox at the first place.

Comment: does not work actually and when i try to click the save button and it does accept my default value

Comment: @AbuHamzah: So have you used a RequiredFieldValidator and set it's InitialValue to "Enter here..."?

Comment: okay so i used RequiredFieldValidator and seems like working but the problem still there for client side, how will i tackle the issue of default value? or is there any good watermark plugin that can be used for client and server side

Comment: @AbuHamzah: Google for jQuery watermark and you'll find something. What problem do you still have? The fact that you need to define the InitialValue for RequiredFieldValue hard coded? You could use a [Resource file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and use inline aspx to get that value: `... InitialValue="<%$ Resources:WebResources, EnterHereText %>" ...`

Answer (score 1):

Sort of looks like you are trying to do a watermark feature on the textarea/textbox's?

Why not check out the html5 `placeholder` attribute? Check out this example here http://jsfiddle.net/k2PLG/1/

The `placeholder` attibute is not a value that is posted or validated against. Also, since you are using javascript, then you can make sure that you include an html5 javascript file which makes this attibute work in older browsers which do not support it.

Comment: Most of the modern browsers do, although IE doesnt, but you can just use some html5 javascript code which creates the same effect when placeholders are not supported.

Comment: well when i click on the link you provided jsfiddle and i dont see watermark so as you said IE dont support the html5 yet so the question is how that code be for using html5 javascript code for watermark?

Comment: There are various jQuery plugins, or other javascript solutions. If you search the web there will be many. Here is one example, although I have never used this one http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html